# Probability of exactly one event occurring

Tags: conditional-probability

Event A has probability of 0.7 and Event B has probability of 0.6. If A and B are independent, what is probability that exactly one occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.  1-P(both)-P(neither), or $P(A \cap B')+P(A' \cap B)$

1 minus zero or both events.  Or (A and not B) + (B and not A).